# PHP domDocument works incorrectly when the node wrapper in figure?

Tags: php, domdocument

I'm trying to add some HTML to all links that contain image.

Basic HTML loaded into dom looks like

```
<div class='content'>
    <a href="..."><img src=""></a>

    <figure>
       <a href="..."><img src=""></a>
       <figcaption>Caption</figcaption>
    </figure>
</div>
```

The code:

```
$content = mb_convert_encoding($content, 'HTML-ENTITIES', "UTF-8");
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($content);

// Convert Images
$images = [];

foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('img') as $node) {
    $images[] = $node;
}

foreach ($images as $node) {    
     $field_html = $dom->createDocumentFragment(); // create fragment
     $field_html->appendXML('<span>11</span>'); // create fragment
     $node->parentNode->appendChild($field_html);  

}

$newHtml = preg_replace('/^<!DOCTYPE.+?>/', '', str_replace( array('<html>', '</html>', '<body>', '</body>'), array('', '', '', ''), $dom->saveHTML()));
return $newHtml;
```

So when it's a regular link with img, it produces correct output:

`<a href="..."><img src=""><span>11</span></a>`

But when it's a figure, output is very strange — link is duplicated and inserted into `figcaption`:

```
<figure>
    <a href="..."><img src=""></a>
    <figcaption>Caption <a href="..."><span>11</span>
    </figcaption>
</figure>
```

Is that because DOMDocument doesn't understand `figure` thing?

Comment: Your code works fine for me: https://3v4l.org/dggVt Note that you can remove the `preg_replace` by adding `LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED  | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD` flags to your call to `loadHTML()`. I've demoed this in my example too

Comment: And you can also get rid of the assignment to `$images`. Just work with `$dom->getElementsByTagName('img')` directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was unable to reproduce your problem. My guess would be a misplaced element somewhere in your source HTML. But your code can be simplified quite a bit.

There's no need to put your image nodes into an array, you can work directly with the results of `DomDocument::getElementsByTagName()`.

As mentioned in comments you can setup [`DomDocument::loadHTML()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) not to add the doctype and implied elements, instead of removing them later with potentially tricky string manipulations.

A simple [`DomDocument::createElement()`](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.createelement.php) can be used for the element you want to append, instead of creating a new object.

Finally, [the error control operator](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php) `@` should generally be avoided. Instead, [`libxml_use_internal_errors()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-get-errors.php) can be used to set the error behaviour. This allows you to examine error messages with [`libxml_get_errors()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.libxml-use-internal-errors.php) if desired.

```
$content = <<< HTML
<div class="content">
    <a href="..."><img src=""></a>
    <figure>
       <a href="..."><img src=""></a>
       <figcaption>Caption</figcaption>
    </figure>
</div>
HTML;

$dom = new DOMDocument();
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($content, LIBXML_HTML_NOIMPLIED | LIBXML_HTML_NODEFDTD);
libxml_use_internal_errors(false);

foreach ($dom->getElementsByTagName('img') as $node) {
     $node->parentNode->appendChild($dom->createElement("span", "11"));
}

$newHtml = $dom->saveHTML();
echo $newHtml;
```

Output:

```
<div class="content">
    <a href="..."><img src=""><span>11</span></a>
    <figure>
       <a href="..."><img src=""><span>11</span></a>
       <figcaption>Caption</figcaption>
    </figure>
</div>
```